# Auto Capitalisation of text in TextView

Tags: android, xml, textview

How do I **capitalise** all the text in `TextView` in `android`?

> android:textAllCaps="true"

works for `ICS` and above but not for lower versions. I wish to do the `capitalisation` in xml and not by using `toUpper()` programmatically.

Comment: please refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Comment: inputType is an attribute of EditText and not TextView.

Answer (score 3):

use `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"`

Comment: inputType doesn't work for TextView. It only works for EditText. I specifically want to capitalise text in TextView.

Comment: so why dob't you pass text in capitals

Comment: I am getting text from cursor and will have to add function toUpper() everywhere in my code. textAllCaps worked well for android 4.1. So I wanted to know xml equivalent for previous versions.